# Change command line argument from kernel itself

Tags: linux-kernel

I am facing an issue where BIOS always ignore whatever I set for cmdline. It only uses a hardcoded cmdline where it send wrong parameter. IN "console=ttys0" "S" is of lower case. I don't have BIOS source code, hence can't change there. I was trying to change lower "s" to Upper "S" from kernel itself. However I am not successful so far. Here is what I tried.

```
void __init setup_arch(char **cmdline_p)
{

     *cmdline_p = command_line; /* Tried to change command_line before this line */
}
```

made changes like below.

```
void __init setup_arch(char **cmdline_p)
{
    {
        char *ptr=NULL;
        ptr=strstr(command_line,"ttys0");
        if(ptr)
            ptr[3]='S'; 
    }
    *cmdline_p = command_line;   
}
```

When I try to boot with this change, it seems kernel hangs. Looks like the moment I try to modify command_line, kernel hangs.

command_line is declared as below.

```
static char __initdata command_line[COMMAND_LINE_SIZE];
```

Does __initdata puts any restriction ?
Any suggestion how can I achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: I think my code change works. However with this change terminal logging stops. Hence it appears like hang.

Answer (score 0):

Changing kernel code is not a viable option. You can change the console by setting the command line in your bootloader.

```
console=ttyS0,9600
```

If your system has ACPI, you can also compile custom ACPI tables into your kernel image which are overriding the options in the BIOS.